# How to generate flattened tables?

Tags: list-manipulation

`Table[f[i,j], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}` generates a list of lists. Sometimes I just want to obtain a single list that contains `f[i,j]` evaluated at all pairs of values `i,j`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a flat table you could use `Tuples`. E.g:

```
f @@@ Tuples[Range[10], 2]
f @@@ Tuples[{Range[10], Range[5], Range[2]}]
```

Comment: Ah, `Tuples`. I suspected there was a standard way to do this, but could not find it. It is also the fastest (kglr answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
Tuples[f[## & @@ (Range /@ {2, 3, 2})]];
Distribute[f[## & @@ (Range /@ {2, 3, 2})], List];
List @ Array[f, {2, 3, 2}, 1, Sequence]
```

> {f[1, 1, 1], f[1, 1, 2], f[1, 2, 1], f[1, 2, 2], f[1, 3, 1], 
>    f[1, 3, 2], f[2, 1, 1], f[2, 1, 2], f[2, 2, 1], f[2, 2, 2], 
>    f[2, 3, 1], f[2, 3, 2]}

```
Equal[%, %%, %%%, FlatTable[f[i, j, k], {i, 2}, {j, 3}, {k, 2}]]
```

> True

**Timings:**

```
n1 = 100; n2 = 200; n3 = 200;
First[AbsoluteTiming[res1 = FlatTable[f[i, j, k], {i, n1}, {j, n2}, {k, n3}];]]
```

> 1.642606

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[res2 = f @@@ Tuples[{Range[n1], Range[n2], Range[n3]}];]]
```

> 1.288345

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[res3 = Tuples[f[## & @@ (Range /@ {n1, n2, n3})]];]]
```

> 0.647329

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[res4 = Distribute[f[## & @@ (Range /@ {n1, n2, n3})], List];]]
```

> 0.706465

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[res5 = List@Array[f, {n1, n2, n3}, 1 , Sequence];]]
```

> 1.243508

```
Equal[res1, res2, res3, res4, res5]
```

> True

Comment: `Tuples` is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

```
FlatTable[expr_, ranges__] := Flatten[Table[expr, ranges], Length[{ranges}] - 1]
SetAttributes[FlatTable, HoldAll]
```

Use it like this:

```
FlatTable[f[i, j, k], {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}]
```

This generates a flattened list:

```
{f[1, 1, 1], f[1, 1, 2], f[1, 2, 1], f[1, 2, 2], 
 f[2, 1, 1], f[2, 1, 2], f[2, 2, 1], f[2, 2, 2]}
```